# C++ Deque / Vector Pushing items in the front instead of push_back

Tags: c++, vector, element, deque

What I'm trying to do is create a reader class that will get the first element , evaluate it and then delete it. So that means the items must be added in the front instead of back.

This is what I need to do. Pseudo-code.

```
void Add( int messageCode ){ if(m_pList && messageCode!=0xFF)m_pList->push_front(messageCode);  } // Adding a message; Added check if input is 0xFF.
```

instead of

```
void Add( int messageCode ){ if(m_pList && messageCode!=0xFF)m_pList->push_back(messageCode);  } // Adding a message; Added check if input is 0xFF.
```

Comment: Deque _has_ `push_front()`, so what's the problem?

Comment: @leftaroundabout A million thanks! I though deques were like vectors, with only push_back/insert support. Add it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4):

If you need FIFO, take a look at `std::deque` class and its methods such as `push_front` or `emplace_front`.

If you need LIFO, take a look at `std::stack` class.

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

`std::deque` has a `push_front` function. It also has a `pop_front` function, to remove it. Indeed, fast insertion/removal from the front is half of the point of a `deque`.

The other thing is this: why do you want to push/pop from the front anyway? Is there something wrong with pushing/popping to the back? You can use a `std::vector` like a regular stack, just by using `push_back`, `pop_back`, and `back`. It would be pretty much identical to pushing to the front. Unless you have need to access the non-front elements in some way, this seems like an entirely legitimate way of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

As dequeue *has* push_front, i guess that you are interested in a solution considering the vector mentioned in your topic.
You can use the [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/) function, which is also available within a [dequeue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/insert/). But as mentioned in the API this might not be efficient. To delete this element you can also use the erase function, also provided by both.